# Get max(date) from table

Tags: sql, ms-access, jet

Hopefully this is a simple one. I have a table of sent messages and a customer table. I am trying to get the date of the last message sent to a customer, but I am having a nightmare with it and can't work out what's up!!

In english: Get me the last date the customer received where the last date is greater than DateX and less than DateY.

In my SQL: (Msaccess)

```
SELECT 
  Max(outgoingmessages.outgoingmessagedatetime), 
  outgoingmessages.outgoingmessagecustomerID 
FROM 
  outgoingmessages 
  inner join customers on customers.customerid = 
                          outgoingmessages.outgoingmessagecustomerid 
WHERE  
  (outgoingmessages.outgoingmessagedatetime>#20/Oct/2012# 
  and 
  outgoingmessages.outgoingmessagedatetime < #02/Nov/2012# )
  and 
  outgoingmessages.outgoingmessagecustomerID NOT IN (
    SELECT incomingMessageCustomerID from incomingmessages
  ) 
GROUP BY 
  outgoingmessages.outgoingmessagecustomerID;
```

I know that `customerid=32` has had a message sent on 05/11, yet the query seems to be ignoring this and showing an old date of his. I literally just need to get the `customerID` and the date of their last message.

any ideas?!

================ UPDATE

I think the statement would work if I could say "WHERE MAX(outgoingmessagetime) BETWEEN date1 and date2)... but I cannot use the MAX date. Maybe I need a sub query?

Comment: What `outgoingmessages.outgoingmessagecustomerID NOT IN (SELECT incomingMessageCustomerID from incomingmessages)` is for?

Comment: Also, it's normal 05/11 is not returned. Your condition is > 20/oct/2012

Comment: You have excluded 05/11 by saying <02/11

Comment: That's what I am trying to achive. If there's a message GREATER than the date range I am looking for, it should ignore the customer. But it's returning the row with an old date. It's like it's not seeing the message on te 5th Nov.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not ... ?

```
SELECT Top 1 o.outgoingmessagedatetime, o.outgoingmessagecustomerID 
FROM outgoingmessages o
WHERE  o.outgoingmessagedatetime between #2012/10/02# And #2012/11/02#
ORDER BY o.outgoingmessagedatetime Desc
```

Note that this will not include messages sent after 2nd November. To include messages up to 5th November, say

```
WHERE  o.outgoingmessagedatetime between #2012/10/02# And #2012/11/05#
```

Re Comment

```
SELECT  o.outgoingmessagecustomerID, Max(o.outgoingmessagedatetime)
FROM outgoingmessages o
WHERE  o.outgoingmessagedatetime between #2012/10/02# And #2012/11/02#
AND o.outgoingmessagecustomerID NOT IN (
    SELECT outgoingmessagecustomerID FROM outgoingmessages 
    WHERE outgoingmessagedatetime > #2012/11/02#)
GROUP BY o.outgoingmessagecustomerID
```

Comment: I need it to be grouped by customerID - so the customer has only the max date (ie: the last message date).

Comment: yes that's correct. I need to ignore any customers who have had the message in the last 7 days. So "get all customers who haven't had a message in 7 days, but also since 20th Oct". Clear as mud!? ;)

Comment: I may have understood what you want, but who is to say :) See my edit above. If it really is a date time (02/11/2012 12:20:00), you may find some confusion.

Comment: Marked as correct as this led me to creating the working SQL. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about this, at first I didn't think the **customers** table was required but it looks as though you may only want to show records that match customers in that table so I've gone for this approach:

```
SELECT A.MaxDT, A.outgoingmessagecustomerID
FROM
(SELECT Max(O.outgoingmessagedatetime) AS MaxDT, O.outgoingmessagecustomerID
FROM outgoingmessages AS O
WHERE O.outgoingmessagedatetime BETWEEN >#10/21/2012# AND Date()-7
AND O.outgoingmessagecustomerID NOT IN (SELECT incomingMessageCustomerID FROM imcomingmessages)
GROUP BY O.outgoingmessagecustomerID) AS A, customers AS C
WHERE A.outgoingmessagecustomerID = C.customerID
```

This carries out the MAX calculation in a derived table and then just links the results back against the customer table

Ps: I wish your field names were shorter ^_^